# how do i change the state of a component after a button is pressed using text input in react native?

Tags: react-native

this changes the state while iam typing but i want the initial state to remain constant and only after completing the text input and pressing the button the state should change

````
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default function app() {
  const [normal, setname] = useState('arun');
  const submithandler = val => {
    setname(val);
  };

  return (
    <View style={Styles.container}>
      <Text>hi {normal}</Text>
      <TextInput style={Styles.Text} onChangeText={val => submithandler(val)} />
    </View>
  );
}

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  Text: {
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 400,
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
});```
**i want the value to be changed only after clicking the button**
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use 2 states:

```js
const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('arun');
const [name, setName] = useState('arun');

...

<Text>hi {name}</Text>
<TextInput 
  value={textValue} 
  onChangeText={val => setTextValue(val)} 
/>
<Button
  onPress={() => setName(textValue)}
  title="Submit"
/>
```